# django difference between two timestamp in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Suppose, I have a timestamp `2018-07-20 14:47:12.984313+06` and I need to calculate the difference with `2018-07-20 14:50:12.984313+06` in Django template. It should return 3 as result.
How can I do this?

Comment: In a template? In general it is rather an *anti-pattern* to do calculations in templates.

Comment: You can probably use the `timesince` template filter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince But then it returns the time expressed in hours, minutes, etc.

Comment: I already try **timesince** but It should not work for me. I need to compare to a timestamp value to use it's value in an if else block.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes I need it on templat. I try on query something like this annotate(minute=ExtractMinute('created_at')) and it return minute from the timestamp for example 2018-07-20 14:47:12.984313+06 gives me 47.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this with [timesince](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/) template tag.